# How to connect to postgresql from files?

Tags: postgresql

Ok, so I have a client who has a postgresql database. He sent me the files (they look like this: http://prntscr.com/fbyz2l).

I have PGAdmin 4 on my windows 10 box. I also have postgres installed locally.

I have the database name and login information... but I can't figure out how to connect to the database.

I am guessing it is pretty simple, but I am having a tough time googling the right thing to get some help.

**Update**

I am still hunting this, but my feeling is the files are not the right format to import or bring onto my localhost. I am asking for a backup file that PGAdmin can make. If anyone has input on this, I am all ears.

**Update 2**

So I copied all the files to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg96\base

Restarted the server. When I do a

```
   psql -h "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg96\base" -l
```

I get this:

http://prntscr.com/fbzxf2

I can connect to template1 and postgres, but neither of them is my database (184429). Ugh...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These files are basically copy of the postgres DB . You need to restore it on your machine . 
You can find default path of postgres DB on `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\some version\data` location . Place the root of these files within that directory and restart your postgres service .

After that you can find new database in your PGAdmin .

Comment: Thanks Deepak. When I look for that directory, I can't find it. I downloaded Postgres again from here (https://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/installers.jsp/) to make sure I had it setup right and it said that it was already installed... I just don't know where!

Comment: What is the directory structure of C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL

Comment: Ok... found it finally. Here is what that folder looks like: http://prntscr.com/fbzc0w

Comment: Ok, so inside C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL/data/pg96/base . you need to put 189429 and reload the postgres service.

Comment: Ok, I did that (http://prntscr.com/fbzedq) ... not sure how to restart the service (yet). Once I do that ... will it show up here somewhere? http://prntscr.com/fbzell

Comment: Yes, after restart if everything works correctly it should show a new database .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145134/discussion-between-david-and-deepak-dixit).

Comment: @David , Sorry but I need to go somewhere.

Comment: Bummer... so I copied those files in there. Restarted the server, but I can't seem to connect to anything but the postgres database...